# Chrome (OS X) number input element value change does not always emit or trigger callbacks

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I've found that Google Chrome input elements do not always dispatch change events, or call onchange handers. It works fine in Firefox, but not in Chrome. This most basic example shows the problem:

JS:

```
function onChange() {
  console.log(document.getElementById('test').value); // Doesn't always get called.
}
```

HTML:

```
<input id="test" type="number" max="99" min="9" size="2" onchange="onChange()">
```

It seems that it works normally when you switch between the increment and decrement buttons, or if you mouse out and mouse back in on the input.

I have created a [plunk that shows the issue](https://plnkr.co/edit/DIXc2fnEfgzGupz8QXQr?p=preview), that also uses jQuery, which fails similarly.

Is this a bug, or am I missing something? Is there a workaround?

UPDATE:

If you add `'input'` to the jQuery events parameter, it works consistently:

```
  $("#test").on("input change", function() {
    console.log('change:', this.value);
  });
```

Still don't know how to make it work without jQuery.

Comment: With `.addEventListener('input', function (e) {...`?

Comment: `document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
    console.log('works');
  });` Like that? it didn't work for me.

Comment: Here you go: https://plnkr.co/edit/N6QLfseQ3xHlTfEYIvSY?p=preview